# FFMPEG Filter Waverform monitor (video)

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

I was using the waveform monitor this way

```
ffplay -i "outnew.mov" -vf "split[a][b]; [a]format=gray,histogram=mode=waveform:waveform_mode=column,vflip,split[c] [d];[b]pad=iw:ih+256[padded];[c]geq=g=1:b=1[red] [d]geq=r=1:b=1,crop=in_w:220:0:16[mid];[red][mid]overlay=0:16[wave} [padded][wave]overlay=0:H-h"
```

I get no units display and do not know what the red represents whether that is 0-15 and 236 - 255 or what.

This page shows exactly what I need

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/WaveformMonitor

The command `ffplay video -vf waveform=filter=lowpass:scale=ire:graticule=green:flags=numbers+dots`

should do what I need, but I get the error

```
[Parsed_waveform_0 @ 0x7f160007ef00] Option 'scale' not found=0/0   
Error initializing filter 'waveform' with args 
'filter=lowpass:scale=ire:graticule=green:flags=numbers+dots'
```

ffmpeg shows me the ubuntu version

ffmpeg version 2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers

I have no idea how this translates to ffmpeg version.

Comment: 2,8 is very old. Get 4.2

Comment: Too reliant on what I am using now to change it on this system. If I break what I have now I will be in bigger problems.

Comment: Keep both. Get a static binary of 4.2 and rename it to ffmpeg42

Comment: It is ffplay that I need. It is not in static builds from what I see.

Comment: I don't think there are public Linux static builds with ffplay. You could also compile yourself and use this version for other purposes (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/).